# Change Toolbar Button Style in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dconf, style

Prior to 14.04 I have been able to do:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface toolbar-style both
```

This used to change my toolbars to icons with text below in all apps that adhered to the rules. In 14.04 it has no effect on most programs (Transmission, Gedit, for instance).

Is there another dconf key for this, or has something else changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### bad news...

Actually, this was a deliberate change by the Gnome Developers.

This is the Git commit -

- https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2013-July/msg02297.html

> Deprecate and hardcode default toolbar style setting
>
> Toolbar style can still be changed on a per-widget basis as needed by the application developer.

Thus, there is no longer a global override method and they left this to individual applications to provide this capability.

I havent noticed that any Gnome applications took up this challenge - so you are out of luck on this.

Comment: I have also noticed it affects only applications that "come bundled" with GNOME - most other apps are flexible. I fail to see the reasoning in this, just as I did when Nautilus was crippled. Nevertheless, we now have Nemo, and perhaps this also gets its remedy one day - hopefully before Ubuntu gets streamlined into a one-pixel orange stripe.